# How copy property of ArrayList in another property of other ArrayList with different property name?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

How copy values of `company` in:

> List personList

To `enterprise` of:

> List employeeList

With Java-8?

I have:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String company;

}
```

And:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String enterprise;

}
```

```
List<Person> personList
List<Employee> employeeList
```

I can't change the property name of `enterprise`.

Comment: Do you want to add a new employee to `employeeList`, which is created from a person in `personList`? Please clarify.

Comment: Look for `map` operation of Streams.

Comment: @DavidLeon is your question resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Employee` has a constructor like `Employee(String name, String enterprise)`

You can convert `Person` objects to `Employee` by using `stream().map()`, then collect new `Employee` instances in a list.

Try this:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = personList.stream().map(p -> new Employee(p.getName(), p.getCompany()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some other methods from Lombok framework, like [Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder).

Also, you could create a utility class for converting `Person` to `Employee`.

And your implementation with ***Stream API*** will be:

```
List<Person> personList = List.of(Person.builder()
                .name("name1")
                .company("company1")
                .build(),
        Person.builder()
                .name("name2")
                .company("company2")
                .build());

System.out.println(personList);

List<Employee> employeeList = personList.stream()
        .map(EmployeeConverter::convertToEmployee)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(employeeList);
```

***Output:***

> [Person(name=name1, company=company1), Person(name=name2, company=company2)]
>   [Employee(name=name1, enterprise=company1), Employee(name=name2, enterprise=company2)]

Other code details:

```
@UtilityClass
class EmployeeConverter {
    public Employee convertToEmployee(Person person) {
        return Employee.builder()
                .name(person.getName())
                .enterprise(person.getCompany())
                .build();
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String company;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String enterprise;
}
```